# Mashape API PHP - No Data Displayed?

Tags: php, api, unirest, mashape

I am having trouble getting any data out of a mashape API, I have made the UNIREST POST but I am unable to echo the data back to myself, this is what the call should return;

```
{
 "result": {
"name": "The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim",
"score": "92",
"rlsdate": "2011-11-11",
"genre": "Role-Playing",
"rating": "M",
"platform": "PlayStation 3",
"publisher": "Bethesda Softworks",
"developer": "Bethesda Game Studios",
"url": "http://www.metacritic.com/game/playstation-3/the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim"
}
}
```

And my code...

```
require_once 'MYDIR/mashape/unirest-php/lib/Unirest.php';

$response = Unirest::post(
"https://byroredux-metacritic.p.mashape.com/find/game",
array(
 "X-Mashape-Authorization" => "MY API AUTH CODE"
),
array(
"title" => "The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim",
"platform" => undefined
)
);

echo "$response->body->name";
?>
```

Can anyone suggest how I can get it to echo the "name".

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the way you are trying to display the body is preventing you from seeing an error in the response telling you that the property `platform` is required to be a `number`.

Try using `json_encode($response->body)` instead to see the full response:

```
<?php

require_once 'lib/Unirest.php';

$response = Unirest::post(
  "https://byroredux-metacritic.p.mashape.com/find/game",

  array(
    "X-Mashape-Authorization" => "-- your authorization key goes here --"
  ),

  array(
    "title" => "The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim",
    "platform" => 1 # try placing undefined here.
  )
);

echo json_encode($response->body);

?>
```

Once you've gotten the response you can then use `$response->body->result->name`:

```
$result = $response->body->result;
echo "{$result->name} has a score of [{$result->score}]";
```